# Rendering HTML from Twitter shows code rather than embeded tweet

Tags: python, twitter, flask, jinja2

I get some HTML representing embeded tweets and want to render them in a template.  However, I get raw HTML code rather than the embeded tweet.  If I manually add the HTML to the template, the tweet shows up correctly.  Why is it rendering code rather than the tweet?

```
@app.route("/")
def main():
    html_list = sentiment.getEmbed()
    return render_template('home.html', htmls=html_list)
```

```html
<div id = "tweets">
{% for html in htmls %}
<div id ="twitter-wjs"> 
    {{html}}  
</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Turn off autoescaping for the HTML, since you presumably trust the data from the Twitter API.

```
{{ html|safe }}
```

Jinja escapes unsafe characters by default to prevent some security vulnerabilities.  So you see what looks like raw html rather than rendered html.